# Firestore: How to use order by field of object of array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database like this.

[image]

How can I order by the timestamp field in the array?

```js
.orderBy("received[0].timestamp", "desc")
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot directly. But what you can do is create a new field on your document called `firstTimestamp` or something similar, and then replicate the timestamp from the first element of the array into that field. You can do that in a Cloud Function or in your frontend/backend code. That way you can sort or filter by that field.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I didn't understand the answer, can you elaborate with an example?